# In python, use relative xpath to find 1st table after given text

Tags: python, xpath

I am trying to find a relative (not absolute) Xpath that will allow me to import the **first** table after the text '**SPLIT TIMES**'. This is my code:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

ResultsPage = requests.get('https://www.iaaf.org/competitions/iaaf-world-championships/iaaf-world-championships-london-2017-5151/results/men/10000-metres/final/result')
ResultsTree = html.fromstring(ResultsPage.content)
ResultsTable = ResultsTree.xpath(("""//*[text()[contains(normalize-space(), "SPLIT TIMES")]]"""))

print ResultsTable
```

I am trying to find the Xpath that will hone in on the 'SPLIT TIMES' table that is found here https://www.iaaf.org/competitions/iaaf-world-championships/iaaf-world-championships-london-2017-5151/results/men/10000-metres/final/result and shown in the image below.

I would be grateful if the Xpath could be as versatile as possible. For example, the requirement may change so that I find the first table after the text which reads '10,000 METRES MEN' (same url as above). Or, I may need to find the first table after the text which reads 'MEDAL TABLE' (different url): https://www.iaaf.org/competitions/iaaf-world-championships/iaaf-world-championships-london-2017-5151/medaltable

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your code because that Website you are trying to scrape uses a protection that will deny the request (the User-Agent is missing in the header as pointed out in the other answer):

> The request could not be satisfied. Request blocked. Generated by
>   cloudfront (CloudFront)

I was able to bypass this by using this library: [cloudflare-scrape](https://github.com/Anorov/cloudflare-scrape).

You can install it using pip:

```
pip install cfscrape
```

And here is the code with a working xpath for what you are trying to achieve, the trick was to use the "following" axe as described in the documentation: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes.

```
import cfscrape
from lxml import html

scraper = cfscrape.create_scraper()
page = scraper.get('https://www.iaaf.org/competitions/iaaf-world-championships/iaaf-world-championships-london-2017-5151/results/men/10000-metres/final/result')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
table = tree.xpath(".//h2[contains(text(), 'Split times')][1]/following::table[1]")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `following` by xpath, something like below.

```
relative_string = "Split times"

ResultsTable = ResultsTree.xpath("//*[text()[contains(normalize-space(), '"+relative_string+"')]]/following::table")
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. It returns 'lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression'. Did you test the above syntax?

Comment: Sorry, i've used this now, 'ResultsTable = ResultsTree.xpath(("""//*[text()[contains(normalize-space(), "SPLIT TIMES")]]/following::table"""))', but it returns an empty value

Comment: If you check the page, SPLIT TIMES is spelled "Split times",